# How could I edit the color of the data elements in highchart graphic?

Tags: highcharts

This is the original js code from the library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 61.41,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: 'Internet Explorer',
                y: 11.84
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.85
            }, {
                name: 'Edge',
                y: 4.67
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.18
            }, {
                name: 'Sogou Explorer',
                y: 1.64
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 1.6
            }, {
                name: 'QQ',
                y: 1.2
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                y: 2.61
            }]
        }]
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify **color** for each data point:

```
data: [{
    name: 'Chrome',
    color: 'yellow',
    y: 61.41
}, ... ]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mvoc016h/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data.color